# Unsupported Item Key in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I am new to Zabbix, i have a requirement to monitor only 1 scheduletasks from a big list of schedule tasks.

I tried below but its not working.

Entry in zabbix_agentd.win.conf

UserParameter=TaskSchedulerMon[*],powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\zabbix\WindowScheduleTasks.ps1 WSTask

Item property file:

```
$TaskInfo = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$name1"
Write-Output ($TaskInfo.State)
```

Trigger Property file:

```
     {TaskSchedulerMon[WSTask].prev()}<>0
```

getting error as "Unsupported Item Key

Comment: Did you restart the agent after making the config file change? What is the full error message?